# AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value

Tags: android

I'm trying to display GoogleMaps inside a nested fragment:

```
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby_map, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

But I'm getting an exception that seem to have to do with the play service version somehow as can be seen from the exception: `Expected 7095000 but found 4323000`

```
04-19 17:20:20.841  20612-20612/com.mahlzeit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mahlzeit, PID: 20612
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 4323000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzJ(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzad(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not sure what I have to do here since the `version.xml` file does contain the value `7095000`:

**version.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">7095000</integer>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity> <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you do not need your own:

> `<integer name="google_play_services_version">7095000</integer>`

and should use the one provided in library. Try removing this entry.

Answer (score 3):

Try Clean the project and rebuild

Comment: You don't have the updated version. you need to update from SDK manager.

Comment: Worked thnx! I had lower version required but found higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find that if there is any another `'version.xml'` file available and in that file replace 4323000(which value you got in error) to 7095000(which value you got in error).